# Parent container with set bounds wraping around any size video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

There are similar questions but I couldn't find an answer to my specific need for the container to be always wrapping around the video without leaving empty spaces (letterboxing), video not to overflow and video aspect ratio not to change. I tried everything, either the horizontal video works or the vertical video works, but never both.

Simple sample code to get the idea across:

```
<div class="parent" style="max-height: 150px; max-width: 100px;" >
  <!-- Mock horizontal video -->
  <video class="video" width="400" height="200"></video>
</div>

<div class="parent" style="max-height: 150px; max-width: 100px;">
  <!-- Mock vertical video -->
  <video width="200" height="400"></video>
</div>
```

I would like any video input to fit the parent container without overflowing and stretching, while the parent container wraps around the video wherever there is empty space not filled with video.

The end result from this should look like this:

[image]

note: wrong height on the second shape. Should have been 150px. Unable to reupload the fixed version.

Here's a JSFiddle link with the clean mock: https://jsfiddle.net/wfhv389j/63/

Comment: Take a look at object-fit: cover along with width:100%; and height:100% on your video childs.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_object-fit.php